# MacBook: Unknown application

Tags: mac

I have been using MacBook Pro for years. Today, about 10 minutes ago, an unknown application appeared on my desktop, see screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

When I click on the text "Wake up" it changes to "sleep", and when I click on "Sleep", it changes back to "wake up". The white part in the macrophone shows the current volume that the microphone "hears" from my room.

What application is this? I am kind of scared ...

Comment: This very well could be a OS level feature. In general for questions like this, include which version of macOS you're running.

Comment: @DylanMcNamee I found it out. It's the "voice control" of MacOS. I feel relieved that it's not a virus, but am still wondering when I (apparently unintentionally) activated voice control

Comment: idk how you did it accidentally, but here's the Apple KB on it [can't test, not on Catalina] https://support.apple.com/HT210539